# How can I send a screenshot by server in python but in pieces of 1024?

Tags: python, sockets, server, screenshot

This is the code for the screenshot:

```
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(r'C:\screen.jpg')
```

I am suppposed to return the image but i dont know how to.

I've tried to open it as a file and read it in 1024 pieces but these are two different def so the response spose to be the file name.

```
with open (response, 'w') as filename:
    data = filename.read()
```

Comment: You want to read it in 1024 byte chunks? First you'll want to open the file in `rb` mode. `w` will truncate the file (get rid of your screenshot). the `b` means you are reading in binary or bytes mode

Comment: `read()` accepts an optional integer argument of how many bytes to read and will return `b''` (an empty bytearray) when there aren't any more. i.e. `data = read(1024)`. Be sure to open the file with mode `rb`.

Comment: ok ive changed to rb but i stiil dont understand how to send it, i want to send the image from the server to the client in 1024 bytes every time and to let the client know when it has finished

Comment: You'll need to use the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#module-socket) module. Here's some [documentation with examples](https://pymotw.com/3/socket/index.html). Until you've done some more research and made an attempt to use it, your question is too broad and off-topic for this website. You might be able to find some examples of using the module here though, so I encourage you to [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+sockets). There's also a [HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) in the online docs.

Comment: Also see question [Read file in chunks - RAM-usage, read Strings from binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056382/read-file-in-chunks-ram-usage-read-strings-from-binary-files) for examples of reading a file in pieces or chunks.